# re-authorize onedrive

Tags: password, cloud, microsoft

I have been trying to find the way to re-authorize onedrive in Ubuntu terminal after I changed my microsoft password. My ubuntu version: 20.04.1 LTS. Onedrive version v2.3.13-6-g38aa7f0.

If I use `onedrive --synchronise` I get an ERROR:

ERROR: OneDrive returned a 'HTTP 401 Unauthorized' - Cannot Initialize Sync Engine
ERROR: Check your configuration as your access token may be empty or invalid

If I use `journalctl --user-unit onedrive -f` I get the following error:

onedrive.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
onedrive.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Followed by the errors mention above.

I cannot find the way to change my access token. Would be great if someone could help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: Don't you have an onedrive or microsoft account in Online Accounts ? You should be able to edit password there.

Comment: Hi Soren A, What I need is a bit more specific. Onedrive is not in the Online Accounts list. So I changed my password online, but my onedrive software that automatically synchronises doesn't changed that password with it. When installing onedrive, the first time onedrive is activated it gives a token and an URL. I need that to happen again without having in reinstall the whole thing. Would you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclosure:** I am the developer of the OneDrive Client for Linux - https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

You are running an out of date / non-supported client version (2.3.13-6) and you need to upgrade / install the latest client. The latest version of the client is v2.4.8-6-g464398d when building from 'master' or v2.4.8 when using the Ubuntu PPA.

Do not use the default Ubuntu packages. They contain bugs and are out-of-date.

Refer to the GitHub site for the correct information for installing the client: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I have upgraded my onedrive by re-installing it and deleting the old onedrive application. After that it indeed worked like a charm. the answer of @Rinzwind is very usefull for the next time this may be needed.

Answer (score 9):

You need to update ...

```
~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token
```

===

Method to authorize:

```
cp ~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token ~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token.backup
rm ~/.config/onedrive/refresh_token
onedrive
onedrive --synchronize --verbose
```

===

To show your configuration:

```
onedrive --display-config
```

In case you used another PATH for the configuration adjust the above commands.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. This seem to do what I wanted. Now, however, when I copy paste the response uri I get an error: onedrive.OneDriveException@src/onedrive.d(874): HTTP request returned status code 400 (Bad Request)
Any Idea?

Comment: Can you do a `onedrive --logout` and try again?